# How to have common axis labels with ggplot2 and patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Given a dataframe `MenRG_Final` containing the following variables:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| P1DistanceRun | Distance covered by the player |
| PointNumber | Point number |
| PointServer | Point server |
| PointWinner | Point winner |
| ServeDepth | Serve depth |
| ServeNumber | Serve number |
| ServeWidth | Serve direction |
| Speed_KMH | Serve speed |

I would like to make the following plot with `ggplot2` consisting in two `geom_boxplot` with common legend and axis labels:

[image: plot goal]

So far, I've been able to make this plot:

[image: current plot]

with this R code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

theme_set(theme_minimal())
```

```r
p1 <- ggplot(
  MenRG_Final %>% filter(PointWinner == "Rafael Nadal"), 
  aes(x = PointServer, P1DistanceRun)
) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = ServeNumber)) +
  labs(
    title = "Nadal a gagné le point"
  )

p2 <- ggplot(
  MenRG_Final %>% filter(PointWinner == "Stan Wawrinka"), 
  aes(x = PointServer, P1DistanceRun)
) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = ServeNumber)) + 
  labs(
    title = "Wawrinka a gagné le point",
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )

(p1 + p2) + plot_layout(guides = "collect") & ylim(0, 60) & theme(legend.position = "top") & labs(x = "Serveur", y = "Distance Parcourue")
```

In particular, I'm wondering how can I:

- Change the legend title and labels and put it at the very top of the plot ?
- Have common axis labels using patchwork ?

If you want to play with the data, I made it available in the dataset folder here: https://github.com/Mathieu-R/ggplot2/tree/main

Comment: Feels like faceting the plot and changing facet label might be the way to go. Without actual data it's difficult to test the results. Can you use `dput(MenRG_Final)` to share your data (or at least part of it)?

Comment: Agree with @benson23. As of the moment `patchwork` does not offer an option  to have common axis titles. But based on your code I would guess that you could achieve your desired result easily by using facetting. And the labels and title for the legend could be set via the `name` and the `labels` argument of `scale_fill_discrete`. Or in case of the title also using `labs(fill= ....)`.

Comment: @benson23 I edited the post with a link to download the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the comments you could achieve your desired result easily and with less code by using facetting:

```
library(ggplot2)

theme_set(theme_minimal())

ggplot(
  MenRG_Final,
  aes(x = PointServer, P1DistanceRun)
) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = ServeNumber)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Premier Service", "Deuxième Service")) +
  facet_wrap(~PointWinner, labeller = labeller(
    PointWinner = c(
      "Rafael Nadal" = "Nadal a gagné le point",
      "Stan Wawrinka" = "Wawrinka a gagné le point"
    )
  )) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  labs(x = "Serveur", y = "Distance Parcourue", fill = NULL)
```

[image]